# Bypass transaction for logging

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, transactions, office365

I'm importing data from Excel to Access. During the import I validate it and I insert only rows that are ok. Errors are logged into another table that is later used by a report. The import is done manually with a VBA macro. I use `CurentDb.OpenRecordset` for writing.

### Current solution: only valid data + keep logs

- I import data from Excel row by row and keep them in the database after the import. Even if I find errors in other rows.
- At the same time I log errors into another table.

### Desired solution: all or nothing + keep logs

- Commit the imported data only if all data is valid.
- Keep the error log also when the imported data is rolled back to show a report.

### Issue

When I rollback the imported data, the logs are also rolledback so I cannot use it for reporting.

### Question

Is there a way to bypass the import transaction so that the log is always written?

Comment: As you _insert only rows that are ok_, I can't see what you wish to rollback.

Comment: @Gustav would you say it's clearer now?

Comment: Since the log records are part of transaction, see no way to preserve if rollback. Instead of a transaction, save valid records to a 'temp' table. Then delete records if decide not to retain. If you do decide to keep then transfer to final table.

Comment: @June7 oh, I didn't know Access had temp tables. This sounds like THE solution.

Comment: A 'temp' table is just a table that is used to temporarily hold records during a process.

Comment: If you have separate databases, you can use two workspaces (the default one plus `CreateWorkspace`), and then commit one and rollback the other. But I don't think you can use them both with the active database. I would have suggested what June7 wrote, too.

Comment: @June7 You do have `CreateTableDef("TableName", dbHiddenObject)` which marks a table as permanently invisible (no way to make it visible besides VBA) and is intended for temporary tables (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/tabledef-attributes-usage)). I personally use that with a prefix and a randomly generated name for my temp tables, that way the user never gets to see them.

Comment: @ErikA I'll give the green tick if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @t3chb0t I don't like half-answers if an actual answer exists, have written an actual answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple workspaces and corresponding database objects, which have separate transactions, even on the database that's currently open. Note that this won't work if you have an exclusive lock on the database.

```vb
Dim wsLog As DAO.Workspace
Dim wsImport As DAO.Workspace
Dim dbImport As DAO.Database
Dim dbLog As DAO.Database
Dim dbe As DAO.DBEngine
Set dbe = DBEngine
Set wsLog = dbe.CreateWorkspace("wsLog", "Admin", "")
Set wsImport = dbe.CreateWorkspace("wsImport", "Admin", "")
Set dbLog = wsLog.OpenDatabase(CurrentProject.FullName)
Set dbImport = wsImport.OpenDatabase(CurrentProject.FullName)
wsImport.BeginTrans
dbImport.Execute "INSERT INTO Table1(Field1) VALUES(1)" 'Do your imports/processing in this workspace
wsLog.BeginTrans
dbLog.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2(Field1) VALUES(1)" 'And logging here
wsLog.CommitTrans 'Commit log
wsImport.Rollback 'Rollback import afterwards
'Result: Table2 is changed, Table1 isn't
```

Note that while it's not *required* to use a separate logging database, if you use Access for storage, I do recommend it.

And, as said in the comments, you can just work with a temporary table too.

You create a permanently invisible table that's intended for temporary use using `CreateTableDef` with the `dbHiddenObject` constant:

```
CreateTableDef("TableName", dbHiddenObject)
```

It won't get removed automatically, so it's not temporary in that sense, though. And keep in mind that deleting + recreating temporary tables will increase the database size, likely requiring more compact operations.